# How to recover Mountain Lion's dmg file after installation?

Tags: macos, upgrade, dmg

I downloaded Mountain Lion from App Store and installed it.

I have not set Time Machine and I installed Mountain Lion one hour ago (since posting this question).

The dmg file is not in Applications folder anymore.

How to recover Mountain Lion's dmg file after installation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After Mountain Lion is installed, your Mac auto-deletes "Installer Mountain Lion.app". So before installs or upgrades like that, you must make a backup (compress it and move file compressed to anywhere, where you put storage data).

And now, you need to download "Installer Mountain Lion.app" again from the App Store.

Comment: No way to recover deleted file?

Comment: As long as time machine is not configurated to backup aplication foler, no, it is not possible.

Comment: even via recovery apps?

Comment: You could theoretically use a data recovery application to get it back, but quite a bit easier to just redownload from the app store.

Comment: where exactly is the file located when downloaded from Mac app store?

Comment: @carbonr: default alway is /Applications folder

Comment: I'm in Yosemite now! Lions are dead. Thanks though

Comment: And for me, I'm came back 10.9 Marverick (on my old macbook 2010, 10.10 very slow although running SSD)

Answer (score 3):

If you open the app store, you'll see the purchase button next to Mountain Lion now says "Download", or you can find it in the purchases section. You have to re-download it but at least you don't have to pay for it again ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Yere if you download the app its invisably stored into your MacBook

Comment: can you explain where on the MacBook the original download is stored?